# Spotify createPlaylistWithName results in forbidden error

Tags: ios, spotify

I am trying to create a playlist with the Spotify iOS SDK, but am receiving the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk Code=403 "forbidden" UserInfo=0x7fb9eb577cf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=forbidden}
```

Here is the way that I am trying to create the playlist:

```
[SPTRequest playlistsForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistList *myPublicPlaylists) {

    [myPublicPlaylists createPlaylistWithName:playlistName publicFlag:FALSE session:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistSnapshot *myRequestedPlaylist) {
            if (error != nil) {

                return;
            }
            success(myRequestedPlaylist);
        }];

  }];
```

I have verified that the session is valid and the SPTPlaylistlist returned from playlistsForUserInSession is correct. What is the correct method for creating a playlist to avoid this error?

Comment: Your application need to have the playlist-modify-public scope to make this request - does the access token you're using have that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Readme from the iOS SDK release, "When connecting a user to your app, you must provide the scopes your application needs to operate. A scope is a permission to access a certain part of a user's account, and if you don't ask for the scopes you need you will receive permission denied errors when trying to perform various tasks."

In this case, it is necessary to give permissions for either (or both) SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope and SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope.

For example:

```
// Create SPTAuth instance; create login URL and open it
SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
NSURL *loginURL = [auth loginURLForClientId:kClientId
                        declaredRedirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCallbackURL]
                                     scopes:@[SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope]];
```